# Which replica does a reader pick in Cosmos DB eveutual consistency?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, replicaset, eventual-consistency

In cosmos DB, one replica-set consists of 4 replicas.
It has one leader and 3 followers (including a forwarder).

I assume that all updates go through the leader first and
the leader is the first one to be updated when updates come
in the replica-set.

If my assumption is correct, a reader does not have to read
many replicas. It only needs to check the leaders in each replica-set to figure out latest updates.

For example, Cosmos DB documentation says that in case of
eventual and consistent prefix consistency models, quorum reads is accessing one single replica. As far as I understand it, the single replica can be any replica in a region. But, if a reader needs to read a update from a replica, does it have to be a leader replica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read operations on Eventual consistency, it can be any of the 4 replicas that are available, so the read will land on any of them, not particularly the leader.

Comment: So, does that mean update events does not hit the leader first in a replica-set? When I see the documentation, a leader is the one gets updates, right?

Comment: Write operations do hit the main replica always. But your question was mentioning reader/read operations.

Comment: If a write is made into the leader first,then I assume that the update is done first in that leader. Then why not readers ask leaders first instead of asking followers? That is the sure way of getting the latest update. Is there any reason or case where a reader does not need to read a leader replica?

Comment: In case of eventual consistency, can you explain what is happening inside a replica-set when an update comes into the replica-set after the update is replicated successfully in its original region or replica-set?

Comment: On eventual consistency, when you read, the read can be served from any replica, you can get dirty reads for sure, and that is eventual consistency. Having 4 replicas to read from means throughput allocated across all replicas can be utilized.

Comment: I understand what eventual consistency is. My question is more like why not eventual consistency uses any leaders instead of any replicas because leaders are the ones that is replicated first in their replica-set. Can you elaborate your last statement "Having 4 replicas to read from means throughput allocated across all replicas can be utilized". Thanks!

Comment: A leader is a replica, Eventual can read from any replica of the Partition, which includes the leader. In a region, the Partition has 4 replicas (1 leader), any of those can be used for an Eventual Read operation, so yes, Eventual includes the leader. Regarding your last question see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#replica-sets, there it says all the replicas in a Partition support the allocated throughput.

Comment: Indeed it is documented here that it will  "as far as possible ... avoid contacting the leader for serving reads" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/global-dist-under-the-hood#replica-sets